# How to add or invite user for facebook group using graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I have created one group manually from my Facebook account(App administrator account).

Now i want to add/invite users using graph API for that Group

```
`$this->fb->post( '/725465137614144/members',array ('member' => '102335487019551'), $accessToken);`


`725465137614144 => Group ID
102335487019551 => invited User id 
$accessToken    => admin user access token`
```

So how to add user in group using group id.

Comment: [This edge was deprecated on April 4th, 2018, and can no longer be used.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/group/members)

Answer (score 1):

> So how to add user in group using group id.

Not possible, there is no API for that.

---

(Yes, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/group/members#publish still mentions it is possible for groups created by the app; but this feature called "App and Games Groups" has been removed a while ago already.)